# Convert map to specific dto object using stream JAVA 8

Tags: java-8

I have a `Map<String, List<Student>>` like

```
AAAA=[com.demo.Student@67b6d4ae, com.demo.Student@34b7bfc0]
BBBB=[com.demo.Student@366e2eef]
```

I want to map to Room like `new Room("AAAA", [com.demo.Student@67b6d4ae, com.demo.Student@34b7bfc0])`

So result will be List of Room contain Room "AAAA" and Room "BBBB"

I want to convert above map to DTO

```
class Room {
    public String number;
    public List<Student> students;
    Room(String number, List<Student> students) {
        this.number = number;
        this.students = students
    }
}
```

I want to use JAVA with stream but Collectors.groupingBy not work for my.

```
 map.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getNumber, Collectors.mapping(roomFunction, Collectors.toList())))
    .values().stream();
```

Anyone can help me and thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create a `List<Room>` from the map?

Comment: Hi @Bohemian yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the map into a list of objects that need the keys and values to create them, stream the map's entries and build the object from those:

```java
List<Room> rooms = map.entrySet().stream()
  .map(e -> new Room(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```